# Nodejs run WASM generated by Golang error but browser success

Tags: node.js, go, webassembly

I create a go file as WASM:

```golang
package main

func main() {
    println("Hello, world!")
}
```

Then, execute following command to generate `test.wasm`:

```bash
> GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build -o test.wasm ./test.go
```

---

I want run WASM in Node.js, ref [Node.js with WebAssembly](https://nodejs.dev/learn/nodejs-with-webassembly):

```js
// test.js
const fs = require('fs');

const wasmBuffer = fs.readFileSync('./test.wasm');
WebAssembly.instantiate(wasmBuffer).then((wasmModule) => {
  console.log(wasmBuffer);
});
```

error message:

```
node:internal/process/promises:279
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Imports argument must be present and must be an object]
```

But, I can execute in browser:

```html
<html>  
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script src="wasm_exec.js"></script>
        <script>
    if (!WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming) {
      // polyfill
      WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming = async (resp, importObject) => {
            const source = await (await resp).arrayBuffer();
            return await WebAssembly.instantiate(source, importObject);
        };
        }

        const go = new Go();

        let mod, inst;

        WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch("test.wasm"), go.importObject).then(
        async (result) => {
            mod = result.module;
            inst = result.instance;

            await go.run(inst);
            inst = await WebAssembly.instantiate(mod, go.importObject); // reset instance
        }
        );

        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

[image]

---

environment:

- Nodejs: 16.15.1
- Golang: go1.18.3 darwin/arm64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I found a way to execute Golang WASM on Node.js:

```js
// commend the block avoid deadlock
// if (code === 0 && !go.exited) {
//   // deadlock, make Go print error and stack traces
//   go._pendingEvent = { id: 0 };
//   go._resume();
// }

// below code is to avoid deadlock
const result = globalThis[func](...funcArgs);

console.log(result);
process.exit();
```

- code: https://github.com/riskers/js-exec-go-wasm/blob/main/solutions/golang/README.md

---

Or you can use tinyGo compile wasm.

- code: https://github.com/riskers/js-exec-go-wasm/blob/main/solutions/tinygo/README.md

---

Universal `cross-wasm` for Node and Browsers.

- code: https://github.com/riskers/js-exec-go-wasm/tree/main/packages/cross-wasm