# Golang to wasm compilation

Tags: go, webassembly

I compile a Golang code to wasm using

```
GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build -o main.wasm
```

I get the following error when trying to execute with wasmtime

```
wasmtime main.wasm 
Error: failed to run main module `main.wasm`

Caused by:
    0: failed to instantiate "main.wasm"
    1: unknown import: `go::debug` has not been defined
```

When executing with wasm3, I get

```
wasm3 main.wasm 
Error: function lookup failed ('_start')
```

What do these errors mean and how to fix them?

Comment: I explored option 3 in further detail and added an edit to my answer. It's actually way easier than I initially thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently no way to use the go compiler to produce wasm outside the broswer. The `main.wasm` in your example is meant to be used with the `wasm_exec.js` shim. There are ways to use it in Node, however. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75379795/20610519) is a previous answer of mine, on the same subject. So, your options are:

1. use Node, as in the question linked above

```
node wasm_exec.js main.wasm
```

2. compile with tinygo, with wasi support

```
tinygo build -target=wasi -o main.wasm main.go
```

`wasmtime` should run this just fine.

3. Secret option three: Go actually has very, very bleeding edge [support](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/58141) for wasm outside the browser. I don't think any release version of the go compiler have that enabled, so that means you will likely have to compile go from sources. After compilation, your command should become:

```
GOOS=wasip1 GOARCH=wasm go build -o main.wasm
```

with no other changes.

For your problem, I would say go with (1), in order to have at least something working, and (2) if you want to run it standalone with `wasmtime`. A new go release should also come soon enough, if you want to wait without compiling yourself.

EDIT:

I had time to look into it myself. It seems that option 3 is not that hard to do yourself:

I followed the instructions [here](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/dl/gotip) to get the latest `go` built from sources, which are just:

```bash
go install golang.org/dl/gotip@latest
gotip download
```

You have to have `go` already installed, in order to be able to do the bootstrap, but any recent version will do. After those instructions, you can use `gotip` just like `go`. So your command becomes:

```bash
GOOS=wasip1 GOARCH=wasm gotip build -o main.wasm
```

As `wasmtime` supports `wasi`, you should be able to run you program without any other modifications to your commands.

The compilation of `gotip` should also not take too much, provided you have a powerful enough computer.