# How do I include a wasm file compiled by golang in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, go, google-chrome-extension, webassembly, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I've tried everything in here:

[Golang to wasm compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76087007/golang-to-wasm-compilation)

And I can't get past:

```js
WebAssembly.instantiate(buffer, {wasi_snapshot_preview1: ""})
WebAssembly.instantiate(buffer, {go: {debug: ""}})

// (i'm making them empty strings just to show I need to add the key but obviously they are not strings.)
```

i.e. I get errors like:

```
Failed to load WebAssembly module: TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #0 module="wasi_snapshot_preview1" error: module is not an object or function
```

or module `debug` or `runtime.resetMemoryDataView` or everything in `wasm_exec.js`

But if I use the `simple.wasm` from:

https://github.com/inflatablegrade/Extension-with-WASM

it works! That wasm must have been compiled by c or rust and NOT golang? Is there a way to make this work from go?

P.S. that `Extension-with-WASM` is manifest 2.0 but I got it work with 3.0:

https://github.com/inflatablegrade/Extension-with-WASM/issues/1

Comment: I'm not totally sure about this but I believe the WASI snapshot error from Go lang could be because of Go still not supporting WASI (Go 1.21 will support this, in this August https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.21).

Answer (score 0):

try compiling with -Oz flag `GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build -o main.wasm -ldflags="-s -w" -gcflags="-trimpath=${PWD}" -trimpath .`

and build `GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build -o main.wasm -tags=js_wasm_profiling -ldflags="-s -w" -gcflags="-trimpath=${PWD}" -trimpath .`

Comment: Failed to load WebAssembly module: TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #0 module="go" error: module is not an object or function

Comment: what version of go you have? run : go version

Comment: go version go1.19.2 darwin/arm64, but I'll upgrade to latest now...

Comment: same error with go version go1.20.5 darwin/arm64

Comment: see https://golangbot.com/webassembly-using-go/ you import correctly syscall/js?